# Can I send notifications from RaspBerry Pi to python kivy application with python client library?

Tags: python, notifications, raspberry-pi, kivy

My project involves the **identification of a speaker** using **Gaussian Mixture Model** whose code resides in **RaspBerry Pi**, from where I record the voice of speaker, process, identify and **send Notification to my Kivy Application**. I'm new to RaspBerry Pi, I searched various tuts but I found tuts which achieved actual purpose but using third party push notification hosted websites based on API key. I want a **python client library** which can send notification from **RaspBerry Pi to kivy application** installed in mobile. How can this be acheived? Thanks for in advance :)

Comment: to receive message it would run socket or web server to receive message. Instead this you can run web server on Rasberry and Kivy may check it periodically.You can also run MQTT queue (ie. [mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/) on Rasberry and send message to queue and Kivy can periodically check if there is new message - you can use module [paho.mqtt.python](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python)

Comment: Can we use onesignal-sdk for the purpose? https://pypi.org/project/onesignal-sdk/

Comment: It seems it needs API key so it will use external server for comunications. And It will work similar way as MQTT - code on RPI will send message to OneSignal server, and code in Kivy will have to periodically check if there is no new message on OneSignal server.

Comment: BTW: using Google "kivy receive message MQTT" I found [Pitoucon: Raspi touch panel with Kivy and MQTT](http://www.weigu.lu/sb-computer/pitoucon/index.html). It runs Kivy on RPI but it should work also if you run Kivy on other computer or device in the same network. For Kivy on device which is not in local network you would have to use MQTT on server in internet or you would have to convfigure routers to forward ports to RPI.